# Ordering with Linq to SQL c#.NET WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

I have a model called `ProjectVersion` which has the following properties:

```
    int Major
    int Minor
    int Patch
    int? Revision
    string PreRelease
    string MetaData
```

Now I am trying to order the versions in decreasing order according to the [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0 specification](http://semver.org) where precedence is `Major > Minor > Patch > PreRelease`

I'm also using Entity framework and Linq to get my data, here is the code I'm currently using:

Note: all less than'<' and greater than '>' signs in the code below are replaced with pipes '|' due to my inexperience with stackoverblow.

```
 public List|ProjectVersionDataContract| GetProjectVersions(int projectId)
        {
            // TODO: Evaluate Versioning system and order list according to it's specification.
            var versions = new List|ProjectVersionDataContract|();
            using (var context = new Entities())
            {
                var vers = context.ProjectVersions.Where(v => v.ProjectId == projectId)
                    .OrderBy(v => v.MajorVersion)
                    .ThenBy(v => v.MinorVersion)
                    .ThenBy(v => v.PatchVersion)
                    .ThenBy(v => v.RevisionVersion)
                    .ThenBy(v => v.PreReleaseVersion).ToList();

                // This uses the AutoMapper package to map the Data Object to the Data Contract
                versions.AddRange(vers.Select(Mapper.Map|ProjectVersion, ProjectVersionDataContract|));
            }

            return versions;
        }
```

Now this get's my data but it returns it with the lowest (oldest) version first, which is opposite of what I want. I've even tried changing the `.OrderBy()` to `OrderByDescending()` with no difference. This is a WCF service if that makes any difference.

Comment: could you .Reverse() it

Comment: didn't realize that was a function, I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: updated the query to `var vers = context.ProjectVersions.Where(v => v.ProjectId == projectId)
                    .OrderBy(v => v.MajorVersion)
                    .ThenBy(v => v.MinorVersion)
                    .ThenBy(v => v.PatchVersion)
                    .ThenBy(v => v.RevisionVersion)
                    .ThenBy(v => v.PreReleaseVersion).Reverse().ToList();` got the following:

Comment: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable'1[Data.Model.ProjectVersion] Reverse[ProjectVersion](System.Linq.IQueryable'1[Data.Model.ProjectVersion])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: Reverse would be after ToList

Comment: @Jonesy got both your comment and Damith's answer at the same time, both were valid. Thank you.

Comment: yeah his solution is certainly better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
var vers = context.ProjectVersions.Where(v => v.ProjectId == projectId)
                    .OrderByDescending(v => v.MajorVersion)
                    .ThenByDescending(v => v.MinorVersion)
                    .ThenByDescending(v => v.PatchVersion)
                    .ThenByDescending(v => v.RevisionVersion)
                    .ThenByDescending(v => v.PreReleaseVersion).ToList();
```

Or you can do as below

```
var normal = GetProjectVersions(idval);
var finalResult =normal.Reverse();
```

Comment: I did the last one. worked great. Thank you for the response.